# How to pass selected value of dropdown from popup to another component in angular 2 without using directives

Tags: angular

How to pass selected value of dropdown from popup to another component in angular 2 without using directives. I can able to get selected value but unable to pass to another component.

```
<form class="form-group" >
    Select server: <select name="serverid" #selectedCategory>
    <option *ngFor="let serverItem of serverItems" value="">Choose Server</option>
    <option *ngFor="let serverItem of serverItems" value="{{serverItem.id}}">{{serverItem.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <p></p>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close('yes',getValueFromSelect(selectedCategory.value))">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close('no')">Cancel</button>
  </form>
```

my function is:

```
getValueFromSelect(value){
    console.log("---log-getValueFromSelect--"+value);
    this.serverItemID=value;
  }
```

SO i want to pass this serverItemID value to some other component. Which is where we are getting popup after drag and drop to right panel of page.

Comment: The other component is not tie to the current component? Is it have parent child relation?

Comment: If I want to read value of drop down list from md dialog box in same component. How can I read?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code,

Child component: 
HTML

```
<select  (change)="changedvalue($event)" required [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="industryType" id="industryType"  aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" class="select-custom">
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                <option value="Business">Business</option>
                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Teaching">Teaching</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
      </select>
```

Handling the output variable

```
changedvalue(val){
    this.emitValue.emit(this.selectedValue);
  }
```

Have the output variable as

```
@Output() emitValue: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Example Parent Component

```
<common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"  (emitValue)="handleEmitValue($event)"> 

</common-modal>
```

Handling the event in the Parent component as

```
handleEmitValue(val){
    console.log(val);
    this.value=val;
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ax2leAh7Z15VIBuLmJHE?p=preview)** With Modal

Comment: @arvind, Thank you for response. But I'm getting error for import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';.

Comment: You need to setup ng2bootstrap

Comment: @vasantha did the above answer helped you??

Answer (score 0):

Use `EventEmitter` to emit data from one component and listen the emitted data in another component. Please refer to this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html).