# Passing data from the child modal to the parent

Tags: modal-dialog, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

When I created a SeleccionServicioComponentMD modal window (child), I used this way:https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component

Inside the  child there is button. When it is clicked:
1) the parent should close this child.
2) the parent should display another modal.

My attempt: The child (modal) emits an event to its parent but:
3) the parent didn't include an `<app-seleccion-servicio-component>` tag inside its HTML because its child was dynamically created. So, where does the parent listen for this emitted event from its children?

The expected result is:
4) click on the button inside the child component.
5) the parent closes this child (modal window).
6) the parent shows another modal window.

7) I am stuck on this point. I don't know how to do so that the parent listens the event emitted by its parent with no `<app-seleccion-servicio-component>` tag.

Comment: can you please add your component's (parent) and your modal (child) code?

Comment: Check this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808877/how-to-pass-selected-value-of-dropdown-from-popup-to-another-component-in-angula/42809562#42809562)

Comment: @ShinDarth, my wrong was:
`@Output() myevent = new EventEmitter<any>(); `

Instead of :

`public event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();`

It worked for me! 

Best regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can't say much without looking at your code but you can create an EventEmitter in your child component and subscribe to it from parent.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/b6qHpolJmUFy7dYvYpkJ?p=preview

```
  /* CHILD COMPONENT */
  public event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  triggerEvent() {
    this.event.emit({data: 12345});
  }
```

---

```
  /* PARENT COMPONENT */
 this.bsModalRef.content.event.subscribe(data => {
    console.log('Child component\'s event was triggered', data);
 });
```

Comment: Hi @IlyaSurmay,

`openModalWithComponent() {
   this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(MyModalComponent);
   this.bsModalRef.content.title = 'Modal with component';
   this.bsModalRef.content.list = list;
   setTimeout(() => {
     list.push('PROFIT!!!');
   }, 2000);

    this.bsModalRef.content.event.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Child component\'s event was triggered:', data);
    });
 }`

causes:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at AppComponent.openModalWithComponent (app.component.ts:31)**

Comment: Could you create a plunkr with reproduction? Now it seems that you haven't created an EventEmitter in child component

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.
This entry was correctly solved! ;)

Comment: It was working ? but why it does not work in angular 9.1.3.... ((message: it is not a function)

Comment: I missed the "public" keyword of event object

Answer (score 5):

Related to Angular 7, I could managed the scenario as follows.

**parent-component.ts**

```
bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

 loadModal() {
    const initialState = {
      title: 'Appointments'
    };

    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent, {
      initialState,
      class: 'modal-lg'
    });

    this.bsModalRef.content.messageEvent.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Child component\'s event was triggered', data);
    });
  }
```

**parent-component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="loadModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

**modal-component.ts**

```
 @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

private submit(){
let msg = "Test Message";
    this.messageEvent.emit(msg);
    this.bsModalRef.hide()
  }
```

**modal-component.html**

```
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```